# Tag log messages per KafkaStreams instance

Tags: apache-kafka, logback, apache-kafka-streams, slf4j

In an app, I have 3 `KafkaStreams` instances, and I would like to have each instance (including all other class instances it uses) log everything using a distinct marker, so that a log setting like the following will print the marker in the log.

```xml
<encoder>
  <pattern>...,%marker,...</pattern>
```

With that, I would be able to distinguish which instance a log message came from. (I already log thread ids, so I can group log messages, but I'd like to use a string to be able to associate a log with the instance that wrote it)

Is something like this even possible? It doesn't actually have to be implemented using slf4j markers, but that's the one Slf4j mechanism that I found works, if I have control over the code doing the logging - which I do not have in the case of the Kafka libraries.

N.B. My slf4j implementation currently is logback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Kafka Streams is already logging the `client.id`, which can be set per instance either directly, or indirectly via `application.id`. It does not extend to all code run by an instance (e.g. AbstractConfig, AppInfoParser, StateDirectory, RocksDB), but seems good enough for me.